# Sql Server - Combine multiple queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Customer` and `Contacts`.

`Companies` table contains information about customers and when an email is sent to the customers a contact is created in `Contacts` table containing information about which type of email is sent and at what time.

Here is an example:

```
Companies:                               Contacts:
------------------------              ----------------------------------------------    
  ID  | Action                           ID   |  CompanyID  | CreatedON  | EmailType
----- | ----------------------          ----- |  ---------- | ---------  | ---------
 Cus1 | 07.03.2014 Registered            Con1 |   Cus1      | 07.03.2014 | NewsLetter
 Cus2 | 08.03.2014 UnSubscribe           Con2 |   Cus2      | 07.03.2014 | NewsLetter
 Cus3 | 10.03.2014 Order                 Con3 |   Cus3      | 10.03.2014 | NewsLetter                  
 Cus4 | 10.03.2014 Registered            Con4 |   Cus4      | 10.03.2014 | NewsLetter   
 Cus5 | NULL                             Con5 |   Cus5      | 14.03.2014 | NewsLetter
 Cus6 | 15.03.2014 UnSubscribe           Con6 |   Cus6      | 14.03.2014 | NewsLetter   
 Cus7 | NULL                             Con7 |   Cus7      | 17.03.2014 | NewsLetter        
 Cus8 | NULL                             Con8 |   Cus8      | 17.03.2014 | NewsLetter
 Cus9 | NULL                             Con9 |   Cus9      | 17.03.2014 | NewsLetter
```

I am looking for a query so that I can see on a particular date how many emails were send and how many customers Registed, UnSubscribed or booked an Order.

e.g.When I run following query I can get how many emails were sent in march according to date:

```
Select Left(convert(date, CreatedON, 105),12) AS DATE_Sent, 
count ( CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, CreatedON))) ) as Alle 
From Contacts 
Where Contacts.Comment Like 'Newsletter' and  
        ( CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, CreatedON))) >= '01.03.2014' and 
CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, CreatedON))) <= '30.03.2014')
Group by Left(convert(date, CreatedON, 105),12)
Order by DATE_Sent
```

I can get How many users registered in March with this query:

```
SELECT Count(Companies.ID) as NumOfRegistered 
FROM Companies, Contacts 
Where Companies.ID = Contacts.CompanyID and Contacts.Comment Like 'Newsletter' And
      ( Companies.Action Like '%Registered%') And
      (Right(Companies.Action, 10) Like '%03.2014'
Group By Right(Companies.Action, 10)
```

In the same why I can get the users who UnSubscried or Ordered in March.

I am getting individual results, I don't know how I can combine these small queries so that I can see all the results together date wise. Any help will be really appreciated. I am expecting the query to give following results:

```
    Date     | Alle |  Registered |   Unsubscribe |  Order |
  ----------   ----   ----------      ----------     -----
  07.03.2014 |  2   |     1       |    NULL       |   NULL
  10.03.2014 |  2   |     1       |    NULL       |    1    
  14.03.2014 |  2   |     NULL    |    NULL       |   NULL
  17.03.2014 |  3   |     NULL    |    NULL       |   NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the numbers from the `companies` table would use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT convert(date, left(co.Action 10), 104) as date
       SUM(case when co.Action Like '%Registered%' then 1 else 0 end) as NumOfRegistered,
       SUM(case when co.Action Like '%Unsubscribed%' then 1 else 0 end) as NumOfUnsubscribed,
       SUM(case when co.Action Like '%Ordered%' then 1 else 0 end) as NumOfOrdered, 
FROM Companies co
GROUP BY convert(date, left(co.Action 10), 104);
```

You an get the numbers from the contacts tables as:

```
select convert(date, CreatedON, 105) as DATE_Sent, count(*) as Alle 
from Contacts c
where c.Comment Like 'Newsletter' and  
      substring(c.CreatedOn, 4, 7) = '03.2014'
group by convert(date, CreatedON, 105) ;
```

You can combine these using `union all` and `aggregation`:

```
select thedate, sum(Alle), sum(NumOfRegistered), sum(NumOfUnsubscribed), sum(NumOfOrdered)
from ((SELECT convert(date, left(co.Action 10), 104) as thedate, NULL as Alle
              SUM(case when co.Action Like '%Registered%' then 1 else 0 end) as NumOfRegistered,
              SUM(case when co.Action Like '%Unsubscribed%' then 1 else 0 end) as NumOfUnsubscribed,
              SUM(case when co.Action Like '%Ordered%' then 1 else 0 end) as NumOfOrdered, 
       FROM Companies co
       GROUP BY convert(date, left(co.Action 10), 104)
      ) union all
      (select convert(date, CreatedON, 105) as DATE_Sent, count(*) as Alle, NULL, NULL, NULL
       from Contacts c
       where c.Comment Like 'Newsletter' and  
             substring(c.CreatedOn, 4, 7) = '03.2014'
       group by convert(date, CreatedON, 105) 
      )
     ) t
group by thedate
order by thedate;
```

Some lessons:

1. Fix you data model so dates are stored as dates and not strings.
2. Use correct conversions.  According to the data in your question, the date conversion format is 104 (see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)).
3. Learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax, where the condition goes in the `on` clause rather than the `where` clause.
4. Learn to use conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Select DATE_Sent,Alle,NumOfRegistered 
from (
(Select CompanyID as id, Left(convert(date, CreatedON, 105),12) AS DATE_Sent, count ( CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, CreatedON))) ) as Alle 
From Contacts 
Where Contacts.Comment Like 'Newsletter' and  
        ( CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, CreatedON))) >= '01.03.2014' and CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, CreatedON))) <= '30.03.2014')
Group by Left(convert(date, CreatedON, 105),12),CompanyID
Order by DATE_Sent) As query1

Left outer Join

(SELECT Companies.ID as id1,Count(Companies.ID) as NumOfRegistered 
FROM Companies, Contacts 
Where Companies.ID = Contacts.CompanyID and Contacts.Comment Like 'Newsletter' And
      ( Companies.Action Like '%Registered%') And
      (Right(Companies.Action, 10) Like '%03.2014'
Group By Right(Companies.Action, 10),Companies.ID) as query2
on query1.id=query2.id1)
```

EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

From Gordon reply.. changing the query to avoid `Null` and replacing with `0`

```
select thedate, 
Case when Alle=NULL then 0 else sum(Alle) as col1, 
Case when NumOfRegistered=NULL then 0 else sum(NumOfRegistered) as col2, 
Case when NumOfUnsubscribed=NULL then 0 else sum(NumOfUnsubscribed) as col3, 
Case when NumOfOrdered=NULL then 0 else sum(NumOfOrdered) as col4
from ((SELECT convert(date, left(co.Action 10), 104) as thedate, NULL as Alle
              SUM(case when co.Action Like '%Registered%' then 1 else 0 end) as NumOfRegistered,
              SUM(case when co.Action Like '%Unsubscribed%' then 1 else 0 end) as NumOfUnsubscribed,
              SUM(case when co.Action Like '%Ordered%' then 1 else 0 end) as NumOfOrdered, 
       FROM Companies co
       GROUP BY convert(date, left(co.Action 10), 104)
      ) union all
      (select convert(date, CreatedON, 105) as DATE_Sent, count(*) as Alle, NULL, NULL, NULL
       from Contacts c
       where c.Comment Like 'Newsletter' and  
             substring(c.CreatedOn, 4, 7) = '03.2014'
       group by convert(date, CreatedON, 105) 
      )
     ) t
group by thedate
order by thedate;
```

Comment: This Query is not returning correct results. The data in NumOfRegistered and Alle is same. Alle should contains all the emails that were sent on a date. But in this query its showing the number of users who are Registered.

Comment: Thanks for the Update.But I got an error                    Msg 1033,Line 8 
The ORDER BY clause is only valid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FROM XML is specified. 
Msg 156,Line 17 
Incorrect syntax near the as keyword.                                                           I removed the Order by but then I got another error:                Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 
The Contacts.CompanyID 'is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Kami sorry missed group by.. updated the answer now please check and let me know

Comment: Thanks again for update!! But I got the same error then I removed Order By Statement. Then I saw the results but Unfortunately, I the field "Alle" its still showing the number of people Registered. But this field supposed to show all the emails sent on that day.

Comment: @Kami you need to check your query on which field is giving you the number of emails... I have just rearranged your queries.. you can see the queries have same fields as in the question... let me know after checking

Comment: Yes the fields are same. I checked your query and I ran the first part by removing 'CompanyID as id' in the Select Statement. Then it showed all the emails sent on the particular date.

Comment: @kami updated answer with outerjoin..should work now

Comment: With Left Outer join it is not grouping the results. And Alle is 1 in all the rows and NumOfRegistered is NULL in all the rows. I think it is showing results according to CompanyID individually not by email send.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and Effort. Anyways, I have updated the question and explained the expected results of the query.

Comment: @Kami you can use Gordon answer as it is very much clear

Comment: Thanks for asking. I am still working on it. Gordon's query is generating the results but not the way I was expecting. First see my expected results. Now Gordon's query generate: First the data in 'Alle' is NULL and rest of fields are filled then 'Alle' is filled but rest of the fields are NULL. I hope you understood what I want to say.

Comment: I would try to help if you can paste the results of the two queries in the same way you have given the expected

Comment: @Savi   I updated the answer. You can see the output of Gordon's query

Comment: @Kami Check my edit tried to avoid `Null` in that process you get `0` and to the extent I know you can't avoid that as result of 3rd query is union of first 2 queries and also 2 queries have different dates so when you do `union` there will be `0` for the results for which data for the `date` doesn't exits.

Comment: So your query just replacing NULLS with 0. Right ??

Comment: hmmm .. Is there any way to handle this situation.

Comment: To the extent I know nothing much can be done with this scenario.... only option is `Dates should be equal in both queries` or `Do a inner join so that only common dates are picked` in this case you loose some data.